# Using UV4L on Raspberry pi 3 with C310

Tags: raspberry-pi, uvc, uv4l

I'm trying to get uv4l working with logitech camera 310. I go to the address XXX:8090/stream and it works for a few seconds then stops. To get it back i need to restart the pi. Also, it sometimes outputs these:

```
Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491012] Internal error: Oops: 80d [#1] SMP ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491317] Process uv4l (pid: 575, stack limit = 0xb29d4210)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491328] Stack: (0xb29d5d74 to 0xb29d6000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491341] 5d60:                                              80611830 b29d5d87 000346db

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491359] 5d80: 80c05dcc 00c02d00 00000004 000005a8 000005a8 00000000 b292d140 b29d5ec0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491376] 5da0: b292d140 00000b50 b29d5ddc b29d5db8 8067a204 80611750 b29d5ddc b29d5dc8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491392] 5dc0: 000005a8 000005a8 b292d220 b6172180 b29d5e74 b29d5de0 8067ad5c 8067a1b4

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491408] 5de0: b29d5dfc b29d5df0 00000000 76149afc b29d5e24 80c06984 80d04818 80c0495c

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491424] 5e00: b29d4020 00000000 00000000 00000000 b29d5e0c b3610000 00000001 b29d5ec8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491440] 5e20: b292d250 00000000 00000000 000005a8 00000000 000005a8 7fffffff a65d0f74

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491456] 5e40: b3782800 80280000 b56b2f00 b292d140 00000000 9888e540 00000121 80108244

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491472] 5e60: b29d4000 00000000 b29d5e94 b29d5e78 806a513c 8067a978 8028fa98 8028fa04

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491488] 5e80: 00000000 00000000 b29d5ea4 b29d5e98 8060a878 806a50ac b29d5f8c b29d5ea8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491504] 5ea0: 8060b914 8060a860 b29d5ec8 b29d5eb8 fffffff7 00000001 7613c388 00001000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491520] 5ec0: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000b50 000004b0 b29d5eb8 00000001 b3610000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491535] 5ee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 b349d6c0 b5991d80 00000000 80b7e940

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491551] 5f00: b29d5f74 b29d5f10 807146b4 8014472c 0000000a 80c7b980 80c71eb8 80c0312c

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491567] 5f20: 80b793b8 00000000 00000001 00000081 76149ae0 80108244 b29d4000 00000001

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491583] 5f40: b29d5fa4 b29d5f50 8019d6a0 8019c92c 00000000 00000000 ffffffff 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491598] 5f60: b29d4000 00000002 b29d4010 00000000 b29d5fb0 73a00480 7613c388 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491614] 5f80: b29d5fa4 b29d5f90 8060b964 8060b858 00000000 00000000 00000000 b29d5fa8

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491630] 5fa0: 801080c0 8060b948 73a00480 7613c388 0000000e 7613c388 00001000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491646] 5fc0: 73a00480 7613c388 00000000 00000121 7613c388 71bac3b0 758ec150 00000001

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491662] 5fe0: 00000000 7533b790 76ec7504 76ec82f4 80000010 0000000e 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Mar  7 18:31:37 ...
 kernel:[  320.491831] Code: a8a0500c cafffff9 08bd8000 e3110020 (18a0500c)
```

I followed this guide http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/installation/. I've watched countless videos of people doing the exact same but it's just not working for me. Let me know if anything else is needed to help figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a kernel oops. This means something bad happened inside the kernel. Most likely, there is a kernel bug related to userspace USB I/O, as that is what uv4l's UVC driver is using. Try upgrading the kernel on your Raspberry Pi and check whether the issue is still there.

The bug might be triggered by normal I/O from the camera, but it might also be that there is something abnormal that causes unexpected data from the camera, which is then badly handled by the kernel. Possible reasons for that could be a bad USB cable or connector, or not entirely unlikely with the Pi, an inadequate power supply that cannot keep the voltage high enough for the hardware to run reliably.